# C# SQL Data Adapter - limit Fill size if query response exceeds a certain row length

Tags: c#, performance, dataadapter

Given the following code that fills in a DataTable object with data from a query:

```
var response = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 30;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

    da.Fill(response); 

    connection.Close();
    da.Dispose();
}
```

Suppose any query is sent through this code.

If the query returns tens of thousands of rows involving several gigabytes of data there could be performance problems. Is there a way to alter the 'Fill' command so it only fills in e.g. the first 1000 rows and stops accepting data after?

Currently when larger queries are returned a large heap space is taken (picture shows a snapshot before and after the fill) and I'm looking for a way to programmatically only fill a certain amount.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Modify the query to select only the first 1000 records

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm writing an interface that allows any query to go through. Are you asking me to programatically add "select top 1000 (query)"

Comment: Yes it's possible you can do a Select TOP 1000 but it's probably best you show us the query also make sure in your query that you are selecting only columns that are needed, also better look into Indexing and running SQL Execution Plan If you know what your conditions are , meaning selecting it based on a where clause this would be even more optimal.. please show the query

Comment: Well, in general i'd not allow that because it's a source of many problems, not only performance related

Comment: There is this overload of [`Fill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Common_DbDataAdapter_Fill_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Data_DataTable___)